# setState (and every other function) inside promise .then() is undefined

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, ecmascript-6, promise

I'm creating a React app with data fetched from Firebase.

When I delete a record with the function below, I try to reload the page to get an updated view not containing the deleted record

```
deleteWorkout(id, e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  fire.database().ref("athlete")
    .child(id).remove() // <-- This works

  // This does not work! 
  //Error: '_this4.getAthleteData' is undefined) 
  .then(() => this.getAthleteData().bind(this)) 
  .catch(e => console.log(e));
```

}

I have defined this function, so I guess it some scope issue in Promise?

```
  getAthleteData() {...}
```

Trying to call

```
this.setState({...})
```

also returns the same error.

Comment: **where** did you define this function?

Comment: you need to bind `deleteWorkout` function

Comment: yes sorry, it have bind it (tried both in constructor and inline like in the question after edit) ... The getAthleteData() function is defined in the same component as deleteWorkout()

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are several issues;

1) If you want to call a function of your class, you should use this keyword.

2) To be able to call this, your function must be binded to the correct place. To solve this, there are several ways.

1. You can use arrow functions as shown below, which will take its parents bind automatically.
2. You can, in your constructor, bind this and override your own method with: `this.deleteWorkout = this.deleteWorkout.bind(this);`
3. You can, when calling the function, provide this to it. `(this.deleteWorkout.bind(this))()`. If you need to provide just the function handle to an onClick event, such as a button, you can provide `this.deleteWorkout.bind(this)`.

Finally, the code shown below should work.

```
deleteWorkout = (id, e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  fire.database().ref("athlete")
    .child(id).remove();
  .then(() => this.getAthleteData()) 
  .catch(e => console.log(e));
}
```

Comment: Ahhh... I had not bound the deleteWorkout function, only the getAthleteData() function. Thanks mate!

Answer (score 0):

It seems like your function is not bound to context with bind or fat arrow ( => ).

Comment: I know... I tried binding it with self = this; I tried binding it in the constructor     this.getAthleteData = this.getAthleteData.bind(this) and inline like in the example... All yields same error

Answer (score 0):

Don't you think you should call getAthleteData() like this.getAthleteData()

```
deleteWorkout(id, e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      fire.database().ref("athlete")
        .child(id).remove() // <-- This works

      // This does not work! 
      //Error: '_this4.getAthleteData' is undefined) 
      .then(() => this.getAthleteData()) //instead of getAthleteData()
      .catch(e => console.log(e));
    }
```

I may be wrong

Comment: You are right... I'll correct it, but it still does not work :/